# Looking for a Beamer Presentation theme that doesn't take up space at the top/bottom so I can fit more stuff on a slide

Tags: beamer, themes

New to Beamer presentations. I tried using themes and they seem to provide very nice features but also take up space so I can't fit as much stuff on the slide.

First, I'd like to get clear on what exactly a theme is and does. Is it just colors or something much more? It seemed like it governs lots of things like slide numbering or progress bar, table of contents, sectioning, theorem boxes, font size?, etc. (I guess you could do those one at a time without a theme but it seemed to help make things simpler?) The problem was that the themes take up space on the top and/or bottom of the slide e.g. with a colored bar or maybe just with a big font size or margins. This means I can't fit as much stuff on one slide which is annoying if I'm trying to convey an idea that requires seeing a bunch of things at once. I'm looking for a Beamer presentation theme that does the normal things that themes do but doesn't take up space at the top/bottom so I can fit more stuff on a slide.

Any recommendations for a good theme fitting my needs? Or if I fundamentally misunderstanding how this works can you reorient me?

Here is an example of a slide with two different themes and no theme. Only the latter has no cutting off of text. (I can fit things I want without the themes but then e.g. the theorem boxes don't show up properly.)

[image: Metropolis Theme]

The above (Metropolis) cuts off maybe just because the font is too big?

[image: Custom Theme someone gave me]

The above (other theme) cuts off because theme stuff is in the way

[image: No theme]

The above (no theme) doesn't cut anything off.

Comment: The most annoying presentations are the one where people put too much one a slide and then simply read out loud from the screen during their talk.

Comment: The comment by Ulrike is a bit strongly worded, but I agree that less text on a slide is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

> I can fit things I want without the themes but then e.g. the theorem boxes don't show up properly.

If you are happy with the default theme, just stay with this theme and add other things, like colours, as you need them. For example the "normal" block colours are set by the `orchid` colour theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{title}
test
\end{block}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]